# SQL-How to get the sum of a column using a union

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to make a query that displays the last name and salary of employees and then the total of the salaries in the row below the salaries. This is what I have right now.

```
SELECT [Last Name], Salary
FROM [Employee]
UNION
Select [Last Name], Sum(Salary)
FROM [Employee]
GROUP BY [Last Name]
```

The union doesn't seem to do anything and the only way I can get the sum of the salaries is if it's the only thing I have in the select statement. I'm pretty rusty with SQL so I'm hoping it's an easy solution.

Here is what the output should look like

```
Last Name    Salary
Johnson      65,000
Anderson     50,000
Smith        70,000
             185,000
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, can you prepare some data and desirable output as well?

Comment: I put a output sample, was that helpful?

Comment: Yes, it's helpful but try to prepare a table of data from which that output generates from.

Answer (score 1):

The query below your `UNION` doesn't do much since it simply returns the last names and their salaries based on your data set.

Try this. It retrieves the total of all your employees and puts it in a row called `Total`.

```
SELECT [Last Name], Salary
FROM [Employee]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', SUM(salary) from employee
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d go with

```
select [Last Name], SUM(Salary)
From [Employee]
Group By Rollup([Last Name])
```

I think it looks cleaner and you essentially just do one table search.

Comment: Access SQL does not support `Rollup`

Answer (score 0):

Use *Null* for the total and sort on the amounts:

```sql
Select 
    [Last Name], 
    Salary
From 
    Employee
Union All
Select 
    Null, 
    Sum(Salary)
From 
    Employee
Order By
    Salary
```

```
Last Name   Salary
---------   ---------
Anderson    50.000,00
Johnson     65.000,00
Smith       70.000,00
           185.000,00
```